# How do I make a Null character in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java, one can use the escape sequence `\0` to represent the [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)

`\0` and `\0000` are not valid escape sequences in Kotlin, so I've been using a static java char and accessing that from Kotlin.

```
public class StringUtils{
  public static char escapeChar = '\0';
}
```

Is there a Null character literal, or a better way of doing this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

These options will work:

- `'\u0000'` (Unicode escape syntax, as described in the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#characters))
- `0.toChar()` ([conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#explicit-conversions) are optimized and have no function call overhead)
- `import java.lang.Character.MIN_VALUE as nullChar`, then use `nullChar` ([renaming import](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#imports))

Starting from Kotlin 1.3, this seems to be the straightforward option:

- [`Char.MIN_VALUE`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/-m-i-n_-v-a-l-u-e.html)

Comment: Working fine only issue is '\u0000' will add two �� .

Answer (score 10):

I believe it must be `'\u0000'`. Please visit this [page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#characters) for more information.